# Библиотека для создания графического интерфейса

Tags: gui, awt, java, swing

Посоветуйте  библиотеку для создания графического интерфейса новачку. Сейчас стоит вопрос не в создание окон, а в примитивной графика. То есть я хочу сделать модель атома в вакууме. Смотрел на awt: вроде легкая, но старая.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`javafx`: новая, красивая, удобная, есть мышкоперетаскиватель под названием `scene builder`, но при желании можно и ручками

Comment: да я про неё слишал, но про нее мало литературы, а я новичек и пока не пережуют и не положат мне в рот я ничего не пойму.

Comment: тогда swing - лучший вариант для начала, потом уже сможете перейти на fx

Comment: Вл**о**димир, Вы, конечно, извините меня, но прежде чем учить язык программирования, я бы посоветовал Вам выучить русский язык.

Comment: http://edu.makery.ch/blog/2012/11/16/javafx-tutorial-addressapp-1/
https://plus.google.com/communities/114965291053640175006?wwc=1

Вот вам на будущее, если решите изучить fx, ну и офф доки само собой

Comment: Обновлю ссылку: http://code.makery.ch/library/javafx-8-tutorial/ru/part1/

Answer (score 1):

[Java OpenGL](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_OpenGL)

> библиотека, представляющая собой прямую привязку функций `OpenGL` к языку программирования `Java`. Является эталонной реализацией спецификации `JSR-231` (`Java Bindings to OpenGL`)

Comment: мне кажется тс имел ввиду библиотеки для создания пользовательского интерфейса, типо swing, qtjambi